# ksoap2 android send custom object as Jax-WS web method parameter

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I am using KSOAP2 (relatively new to me) with an android client to access a soap web service which I designed myself. So far, I have been able to

- Receive and process Simple(Primitives) and Custom objects
- Send send primitives as web method parameters.
- Serialize my custom class and build soap request. This what the request looks like:

  ```
  <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <v:Header />
      <v:Body>
          <n0:insertRequestForApp id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://www.mynamespace.com">
              <arg0 i:type="n0:AppRequest">
                  <reqId i:type="d:int">0</reqId>
                  <parm1Id i:type="d:int">1</parm1Id>
                  <param1UserId i:type="d:int">1</parm1UserId>
                  <param2Id i:type="d:int">1</parm2Id>
                  <param2UserId i:type="d:int">3</parm2UserId>
                  <status i:type="d:int">1</status>
                  <type i:type="d:int">1</type>
              </arg0>
              </n0:insertRequestForApp>
      </v:Body>
  </v:Envelope>
  ```

The return i get from the service is `<return>false</return>`

This is the service method that is invoked

```
public boolean addRequest(AppRequest req){
    boolean ret = true;
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement("insert into appointment_requests(status, param1_id, param1_Users_id,"
                        + "param2_id, param2_Users_id, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, req.getStatus());
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, req.getParam1tId());
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, req.getParam1UsersId());
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, req.getParam2Id());
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, req.getParam2UsersId());
        preparedStatement.setInt(6, req.getType());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ret = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}`
```

The above database insert code has been tried with normal Java code and it works fine with the values gotten from the service call by the android client, but the server log when the call is made from KSoap2 suggests a `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` exception.

**Please Help Anyone?**
**UPDATE:**
I have printed the output the object that is received in the database class and its not the same as the one sent. The received version looks like this:
`Param2 Id: 1 
Param2 User Id: 0 *(instead of 3 in the soap message)* 
Param1 Id: 1 
Param1 User Id: 0 *(instead of 1 in the soap message)* 
Status: 1 
Type: 1`

Looks like there is a problem when de-serializing the object